# How to obtain user id for userdisp.aspx page

Tags: user-profile-service, user-profile-property, person

I have SP 2013 farm. When i want to see user, SP render for me link like this: http://portal/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=1. Then i go for this link become redirect to http://portal/my/Person.aspx?accountname=userlogin.
I want to obtain user ID from first link. But if i search user via SP search it always give me a link to Person.aspx. 
I saw a Profile in User Profile Service Application and can't find a property like ID.
How can i get this id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but in my case I went into the list settings for the User Information List in SP2013 and created a new view that included several columns, including the ID for each user:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly elegant but if you view your site collection access group with Id=0 you can find the user then hovering the mouse over that user the ID= for that user will display in the link preview.

1. Go to:
   https://portal/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0
2. Find the user and hover mouse over
3. Look at bottom of screen for link preview
4. The ID= is found at the very end of the link preview

Hopefully someone else knows a better way and can post.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the UserID from any place in SharePoint that displays the User Name, such as Modified by in a List or Library. Right-click on the User Name and select Properties from the flyout. It will give you `userdisp.aspx?ID=39` for that that user.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the userIds via REST:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_User

A GET request on `http://site_url/_api/web/siteusers` gives you a list of all siteusers. For each user there is a field `"Id" : 1` (in JSON Format).

Trap: The ID differs per website collection!
So if you need IDs for a specific website collection you have to request 
`http://site_url/website_collection/_api/web/siteusers`

If you already know the username and just want to obtain the ID you can get it by requesting `http://site_url/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='login name'` as explained in the MSDN Link.